# How to setValue of Image from Firebase recycler adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to setValue of Image url from Firebase database to view but no result found .I think it is very easy for a regular firebase programmer.Please help me .

Here is my Code:

Veglist.java

```
public static class VegViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View mView;
    private ImageView postImage;
    private TextView quantityBox,postVegName,postPrice,postPriceTag;
    private ImageButton reducequantityButton,increaseQuantityButton;
    private Button add;
    private String mPostKey=null;
    String totalCost;


    public VegViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;


        add=(Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        quantityBox=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        reducequantityButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.downQuantitybutton);
        increaseQuantityButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.upQuantitybutton);
                cartobject.child("Name").setValue(postVegName.getText().toString().trim());
cartobject.child("Image").setValue(postImage.toString()); cartobject.child("Price").setValue(postPrice.getText().toString().trim()); cartobject.child("PriceTag").setValue(postPriceTag.getText().toString().trim()); cartobject.child("Quantity").setValue(quantityBox.getText().toString());

                totalCost = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(quantityBox.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(postPrice.getText().toString()));

                cartobject.child("Total").setValue(totalCost).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        p.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), postVegName.getText().toString().trim() + " successfully added to cart! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        add.setText("Added");
                        add.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5625D2"));


                    }

                });
            }
        });





    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        postVegName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.vegName);
        postVegName.setText(name);

    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        postPrice = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.VegPrice);
        postPrice.setText(price);


    }

    public void setPriceTag(String priceTag)
    {
        postPriceTag=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.PriceTag);
        postPriceTag.setText(priceTag);
    }

    public void setImage(Context context, String image) {
        postImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.VegImg);
        Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(postImage);
    }






}

public void setUpVegAdapter(final Query reference) {

    vegRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Veg, VegViewHolder>
            (

                    Veg.class,
                    R.layout.row_layout_veg,
                    VegViewHolder.class,
                    mainReference
            )

    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final VegViewHolder viewHolder, final Veg model, int position) {


            try {


                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                viewHolder.setPriceTag(model.getPriceTag());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("start error", "useless");
            }


        }


    };


}
```

What should I use for image?

```
cartobject.child("Image").setValue(??????????);
```

Comment: If the image comes from an URL, why not store the URL?

Comment: Can you tell me how I store the image URL ?? Above is my code..

Comment: Assuming `ref` is the `FirebaseReference` where you would want the URL to be and `url` a `String` with the url of the image you want to save, you can write `ref.setValue( url );`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this is to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and pass in the photo URL.

The Firebase Android Codelab has an example of how to do this in [step 7](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#6) (do a ctrl+f for Glide).

Answer (score -1):

If You Know the Image Url from the imageview
just do

```
    cartObject.child("image).setValue(urlOfImage.tostring)
```

If you are rather uploading from phone first You Can Do this

First Add this

```
public Uri resultUri=null;
private ImageView postImage;
```

Then Second Initialise

```
 postImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.postImage);
```

Third setOnclickListner For The ImageView

```
 postImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.startPickImageActivity(this);
            }
        });
```

Then You Do

```
  @Override
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .start(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "After image select");
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            resultUri = result.getUri();
            profilepic.setImageURI(resultUri);
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "After image crop");
    }
}

public void uploadImage() {

    StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child(resultUri.getLastPathSegment());

    riversRef.putFile(resultUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                   postImageUrlToString = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                   cartObject.child("image").setValue( postImageUrlToString)


                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    // ...
                  //  updateUserData(nametext.getText().toString(),getUriToDrawable(ProfileActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_account_black_56dp));

                }
            });
}
```

You  might need this dependency

```
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
```

Comment: Please reformat your question, right now all of it appears as `code`.